# Generate all combinations of given list of elements, sorted

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

Make a code that takes a list and a number as input, and generates all possible combinations with the length of the number. For example, with the list **{0,1}** and the number **2**:

```
00
01
10
11
```

**Your program doesn't have to expect characters twice or more often in the list, such as** *{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,5,5}*

**Make sure you print the combinations out sorted, in the order of the list:**

With the list **{0,1}** and the number **5** (generated by some of my code, which is a way too long to win):

```
00000
00001
00010
00011
00100
00101
00110
00111
01000
01001
01010
01011
01100
01101
01110
01111
10000
10001
10010
10011
10100
10101
10110
10111
11000
11001
11010
11011
11100
11101
11110
11111
```

**But with the list *{1,0}* and the number *2*:**

```
11
10
01
00
```

As you can see, reversed list means reversed order.

Take a look at the structure, it's like a tree.

This is code-golf, so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: I thought this would be duplicate, but I can't find one

Comment: How does the sorting work if the input list isnt sorted?

Comment: @Jarko I'd assume the tuples of _indices_ of the input are sorted in the output

Comment: Can the output be a list of lists `((0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1))` from a function?

Comment: @brad, the default answer is yes unless OP has said something else.

Comment: What StewieGriffin says is right.

Comment: @StewieGriffin I never understand why people would pick a username like that. Why would you :O?

Comment: I don't understand... what's wrong with using my own name as a username?

Comment: Do we have to handle lengths of 0?

Comment: No, you wont have to.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 [byte](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṗ
```

**[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmX&input=&args=WzAsMV0+NQ)**

Cartesian power built-in atom, as a dyadic link with left argument the items and right argument the count, or as a full program with first argument the items and second argument the count.

Comment: One byte ! That solved it !

Comment: You know what, I'm gonna submit a ZERO byte answer! In JAVA! How do you like that, huh? :) (Seriously, though. Nice golfing.)

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, 20 bytes

```
(mapM id.).replicate
```

Usage exaple:

```
*Main> ( (mapM id.).replicate )  2 "01" 
["00","01","10","11"]
*Main> ( (mapM id.).replicate )  2 "10" 
["11","10","01","00"]
```

`replicate` makes `n` copies of the 2nd parameter and `mapM id` builds the combinations. Btw, `mapM id` is the same as `sequence`, but 1 byte less.

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 2 bytes

```
Z^
```

Cartesian power builtin...

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Wl4&input=WzAgMV0KNQ)

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, 2 bytes

```
^F
```

A program that takes input in the form `list,number` and prints a list of lists.

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%5EF&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%2C1%5D%2C2%0A%5B0%2C1%5D%2C5%0A%5B1%2C0%5D%2C2&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
^F   Program. Input: Q
^FQ  Implicit input fill
 F   Fold
^    repeated Cartesian power
  Q  over Q
     Implicitly print
```

Comment: this seems to solve it, but probably somebody else is able to do this with one byte ?

Comment: yes, somebody else won(jelly, one byte) but nice solution, anyway

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 15 bytes

```perl6
{[X] @^a xx$^b}
```

### Explanation:

```perl6
{[X] @^a xx$^b}

{             } # bare block lambda

     @^a        # declare first parameter as Positional
           $^b  # declare second parameter
         xx     # list repeat ｢@a｣, ｢$b｣ times

# at this point given ｢ (0,1), 5 ｣
# ((0 1) (0 1) (0 1) (0 1) (0 1))

 [ ]            # list reduce
  X             #    using cross meta-operator

# results in a list of lists
# ((0 0 0 0 0)
#  (0 0 0 0 1)
#  (0 0 0 1 0)
#  (0 0 0 1 1)
#  (0 0 1 0 0)
#  (0 0 1 0 1)
#  ...
#  (1 1 1 1 1))
```

```perl6
say {[X] $^a xx$^b}( (0,1), 2 ); # ((0 0) (0 1) (1 0) (1 1))
say {[X] $^a xx$^b}( (1,0), 2 ); # ((1 1) (1 0) (0 1) (0 0))
say {[X] $^a xx$^b}( (0,1,2), 2 );
# ((0 0) (0 1) (0 2) (1 0) (1 1) (1 2) (2 0) (2 1) (2 2))

put {[X] $^a xx$^b}( (0,1), 5 )».join;
# 00000 00001 00010 00011 00100 00101 00110 00111 01000 01001 01010 01011 01100 01101 01110 01111 10000 10001 10010 10011 10100 10101 10110 10111 11000 11001 11010 11011 11100 11101 11110 11111
```

Comment: If they ever upgrade to a release of [Rakudo](http://rakudo.org) from after the official release of [Perl 6](https://perl6.org) you will be able to run this at [Ideone](https://ideone.com/8CG9Gz).

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (Firefox 30+), 55 bytes

```
f=(a,n)=>n?[for(b of a)for(c of f(a,n-1))[b,...c]]:[[]]
```

I'm 99% certain recursion is the best way to go about this in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 6 bytes

```
Tuples
```

Still worse than Jelly :(

## Usage

```
Tuples[{0, 1}, 5]
```

> `{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}`

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 30 bytes

28 bytes of code + `-nl` flag.

```
$"=",";say for glob"{@F}"x<>
```

To run it:

```
perl -alE '$"=",";say for glob"{@F}"x<>' <<< "1 0
2"
```

I think that taking the input as a list of numbers is logical for Perl. However, if we allow some fantasy, and take the input with the brackets and comma (as shown in the question), we can go down to **20 bytes**:

```
perl -nlE 'say for glob$_ x<>' <<< "{1,0}
2"
```

**Explanations:**
`glob` initial purpose in Perl is list and iterate through filenames, but when its argument contains curly brackets, it generates combinations formed of one element of each bracket group.
`-a` autosplit on spaces the input, and put the result inside `@F` array.
`$"` is the list separator: it's the separator inserted between the elements of a list inside a string. We set it to `,`, so `"{@F"}` produces `{.,.}` (if `@F` contains 0 and 1).
Then `x` is the string repetition operator (and `<>` gets one line of input).
And finally, `say for` iterates through the list generated by `glob` and prints the elements.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 57 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
lambda o,n:list(product(*([o]*n)))
```

**[repl.it](https://repl.it/EmhD)**

Unnamed function taking a list of objects, `o` and a count, `n` and returning a list of the combinations.

Answer (score 3):

## Pure Bash, 36

```bash
printf -vv %$2s
eval echo ${v// /$1}
```

Input by command-line params - The list is a comma-separated list in braces, e.g.:

```bash
./elemcombo.sh "{0,1}" 2
```

Note the input list needs to be quoted so the calling shell does not expand it too early.

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/bZ1geQ).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It only repeats the input n times, doesn't print all possible combinations.

Comment: @IporSircer I clarified the required input format.  Does that work for you now?

Comment: `bash a.sh "{0,1}" 2` --> `{0,1}{0,1}` (version 4.4.5(1)-release)

Comment: @IporSircer I just git-cloned and built 4.4.5(1)-release and I get the correct output `00 01 10 11`.  What is your output when you invoke bash with a `-x`?  Do you see this answer works in the Ideone link?

Comment: Hmm, strange. The code on Ideone is working for me correctly. But when i copypaste the function to a single file, it gets wrong. Making function is the key. See yourself at: https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@19QlJlXkqagW1amoKpiVMyVWpaYo5CanJGvoFJdpq@voK9iWPv//3@lagMdw1olBSMA

Comment: @IporSircer It looks like TIO is probably putting the args into an execve() or similar call.  The quotes are only needed when the script is called from another shell in order to prevent the calling shell from doing expansion of the braces.  I the TIO case, the list does not need quotes.  https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@19QlJlXkqagW1amoKpiVMyVWpaYo5CanJGvoFJdpq@voK9iWPv///9qAx0gbQQA

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>53</s> 45 bytes

```r
function(x,n)rev(expand.grid(rep(list(x),n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQidPsyi1TCO1oiAxL0UvvSgzRaMotUAjJ7O4RKNCEyirqfk/TcPAylDHVPM/AA)

`rev` is there to the conform with the precise sort order requested (which doesn't really seem essential to the problem) and adds 5 bytes.

Comment: Just `rev` for [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQidPsyi1TCO1oiAxL0UvvSgzRaMotUAjJ7O4RKNCEyirqfk/TcPAylDHVPM/AA) :)

Comment: Had matrix on the mind and forgot the result was actually a list (data frame).

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>2</s> 1 [byte<s>s</s>](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ã
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Emigna*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8OL//025og10DGMB)

Input as `number\nlist`, output as list of lists.

**Explanation:**

```
     # Implicit input `a`, `b`
ã    # Take the Cartesian product of list `b` repeated `a` times
```

Comment: You don't need the `I` here.

Comment: @Emigna Ah of course. I had the `I` because I initially was trying to figure out how to have multiple inputs and had the number and list reversed. Pretty stupid to keep the `I` there.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 123 bytes

```
(let p((s "")(l(map number->string(sort l <))))
(if(= n(string-length s))(displayln s)(for((i l))(p(string-append s i)l))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define(f l n)
  (let loop ((s "")
             (l (map number->string (sort l <))))
    (if (= n (string-length s))
        (displayln s)
        (for ((i l))
          (loop (string-append s i) l)))))
```

Testing:

```
(f '(0 1) 2)
(f '(0 1) 3)
(f '(0 1) 5)
```

Output:

```
00
01
10
11

000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111

00000
00001
00010
00011
00100
00101
00110
00111
01000
01001
01010
01011
01100
01101
01110
01111
10000
10001
10010
10011
10100
10101
10110
10111
11000
11001
11010
11011
11100
11101
11110
11111
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 109 bytes

```
for($o=$a=array_slice($argv,2);--$argv[1];$o=$c,$c=[])foreach($a as$n)foreach($o as$s)$c[]=$n.$s;print_r($o);
```

Takes the length as the first argument and the list as any further arguments.
Use like:

```
php -r "for($o=$a=array_slice($argv,2);--$argv[1];$o=$c,$c=[])foreach($a as$n)foreach($o as$s)$c[]=$n.$s;print_r($o);" 5 0 1
```

Will run into an "out of memory" fatal error if asked for length 0.

Comment: You wont have to handle length 0.