# LaTeX truth tables

Tags: code-golf, math

Write a program or a function that accepts the list of outputs from a logic function and outputs the LaTeX code for its truth table.

The inputs should be labeled as lowercase letters `a-z`, and the output should be labelled as `F`. The length of list of inputs will always be shorter than `2^25`, which means that number of inputs will always be less than 25, so you can use letters from lowercase alphabet for input names.

### Input

A number `n` of inputs and list of length `2^n` of binary numbers which represents the outputs of a logical function.

### Output

LaTeX code that produces the truth table for that function. Input and output values should be centered in rows.
There must be a line between table header and its values and between inputs and output, so the code should be similar to that below.

```
\begin{tabular}{c * <NUMBER OF INPUTS>|c}
<INPUTS>&F\\
\hline
<INPUT VECTOR i>&<OUTPUT>\\
\end{tabular}
```

### Example

Input:

```
2
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Output:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc|c}
a & b & F \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Which when displayed in LaTeX shows the following truth table

[image: Truth table]

### General rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Comment: Is this challenge require exactly same output or any output that may produce same thing in TeX?

Comment: Any output that produces the same thing in TeX

Comment: Can the list be input as a string of 2ⁿ binary digits e.g. `2, 0001`?

Comment: Does the latex code need to produce the exact output formatting given? Can it have other lines?

Comment: @Neil, the output can be a string, xnor no, the format should not have other lines

Comment: Suggested test case: `3` and `[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]`.

Comment: Something I find tricky here not knowing TeX that well is that there might be other shorter ways to write the table formatting TeX code, or even some other way (package?) to produce the table. Whatever language I use, TeX golf is part of the challenge. Is there an online interpreter for TeX for convenience, and perhaps to make unambiguous what the exact implementation is?

Comment: Tip: The TeX code seems to work with all spaces and newlines removed.

Comment: Anyone who doesn't know how to do it in LaTeX, follow the example output above. If n=5, simple put `ccccc` instead of `cc`, but leave `|c` alone... And yes, in this table, all spaces and newlines are optional, but I would avoid blank lines.

Comment: Are lines compulsory? Is TeX instead of LaTeX allowed?

Comment: Can we take the binary numbers as a list of characters?

Comment: @xnor Yes you can

Comment: Here's how to do it in TeX: `\halign{\hfil#\hfil&\hfil#\hfil&\strut\vrule\hfil#\hfil\cr   \ a &\ b &\ F \cr   \noalign{\hrule}   0&0&0\cr   0&1&0\cr   1&0&0\cr    1&1&1\cr}`. There are `\cr` instead of `\\`. Yes, I still prefer TeX from LaTeX, I feel more in control.

Comment: An alternative approach in TeX: `\valign{\hbox to 1em {\strut\hfil#\hfil}\hrule&\hbox to 1em {\strut\hfil#\hfil}&\hbox to 1em {\strut\hfil#\hfil}&\hbox to 1em {\strut\hfil#\hfil}&\hbox to 1em {\strut\hfil#\hfil}\cr   a&0&0&1&1\cr   b&0&1&0&1\cr   \noalign{\vrule}   F&0&0&0&1\cr}`. Looks worse, but with vertical alignment it may be easier because the first part (until the `\noalign` bit) is purely dependent on n and the second part (the last column) is just the `&`-delimited list of values.

Comment: Related question: [Generate all combinations of given list of elements, sorted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/102835/80010)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 70 bytes

```
≔tabularζ\ζ{*θc|c}⸿⪫✂β⁰Ｉθ¹&⁰&F\\⸿\hline⸿Ｅη⁺⪫⁺⮌ＥＩθＩ﹪÷κＸ²λ²⟦ι⟧&¦\\⁰\endζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBNC8IwDL37K0oPo5MK3a6eRBEUBkOP1kPtiiuWVtttgh@/vXZTNgUDCclL8vIIL5nlhinvZ87Jo0awYodaMQsxuMXTUW6lrhCkFPbFF3wfD/BlgPmDP6kdWmsjNdoqyQU6YEAwmDPXLmCQBIcRjPtRMrBES9qapaWSWnzzZeyMSgxyVbs3d5dtRCOsE123P9AlmSlqZdBKVwvZyEKgU1g2V2FRioGKw1gat3En9x89Iba3g7B/yigVuvh5iPfpiBCS@EmjXg) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔tabularζ
```

Save this string in a variable to avoid duplication.

```
\ζ{*θc|c}⸿
```

Print the initial `\tabular{*2c|c}` line (2 or whatever value the first input `q` has).

```
⪫✂β⁰Ｉθ¹&⁰&F\\⸿\hline⸿
```

Get the first `q` letters from the predefined variable `b` and insert `&`s between them, then append the `&F\\` and also print `\hline` on the next line.

```
Ｅη⁺⪫⁺⮌ＥＩθＩ﹪÷κＸ²λ²⟦ι⟧&¦\\
```

Loop over the characters in the second input. For each one, its index is converted to binary with length `q`, the character is concatenated, the result is joined with `&`s and `\\` is appended. The resulting strings are implicitly printed on separate lines.

```
⁰\endζ
```

Print the `\endtabular`. (The `⁰` is just a separator as the deverbosifier forgots to insert a `¦`.)

Comment: It's kinda impressive that Charcoal is currently the winner, given that this challenge isn't really what it's designed for.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 153 bytes

```python
lambda n,l:r'\tabular{*%dc|c}%s&F\\\hline%s\endtabular'%(n,q(map(chr,range(97,97+n))),r'\\'.join(q(bin(2**n+i)[3:]+x)for i,x in enumerate(l)))
q='&'.join
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYw7DoMwGIN3TpEFkkBU8RgQSKy9BGEIEEqq8AMBJKq2Z6dIhaqD7eGzPTzmtodwazK@adGVtUDAdGown0W5aGGerl1Xr@ptT86Vc95qBdKeuIT6KGCbABtJJwZStYYZATdJkpglsQeUUrZfcXy59wrISMrdQ9cFT9E8SgtvpU1vkGIrUoAkLJ00YpZE70NrzLDzHW6DUTCjhoQM5djH7KcAF9Q6aXTS4JD/l2d7@wA)

Outputs like

```latex
\tabular{*2c|c}a&b&F\\\hline0&0&0\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\\1&1&1\endtabular
```

`\tabular` and `\endtabular` are used as shorter `\begin{tabular}` and `\end{tabular}`, as per [this LaTeX golf tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124042/20260). The `*2c` is a shorthand to define 2 columns.

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>164</s> 155 bytes

```
s%f=((:"&")=<<s)++f:"\\\\"
n#r=unlines$("\\tabular{"++('c'<$[1..n])++"|c}"):take n['a'..]%'F':"\\hline":zipWith(%)(mapM id$"01"<$[1..n])r++["\\endtabular"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY07D4MgGEX3/gryiQVDQiTdiKzdOnXoYB2oj0hEYhCXPn47xaTpHW/uOXfU69RbG@OaD4pSCUcoVFWtBWODhHsKHFzm1eascf2KaeqCfmxW@xcwRklLKlwLzl2TEHi3Hyhk0FOPXE004bzJyZnspnEXgHya5WbCSPOCznq5INNhKAX8JZ6xOq171/1uoImzNg4ptGzhGjzC6IQyBGVZCiESGr8)

```
unlines                               -- take a list of strings and join it with NL.
                                      -- the strings are:
   "\\tabular{"++('c'<$[1..n])++"|c}" -- tabular definition with n times 'c'
   take n['a'..]%'F'                  -- table header
   "\\hline"                          -- hline
   zipWith(%)(mapM id$"01"<$[1..n])r  -- table content
   ["\\endtabular"]                   -- end of tabular definition

Table header and content are built via function '%'

s%f=                                  -- take a string 's' and a char 'f'
    ((:"&")=<<s)                      -- append a "&" to each char in 's'
    ++f:"\\\\"                        -- and append 'f' and two backslashes

Table header:

take n['a'..] % 'F'                   -- s: the first n letters from the alphabet
                                      -- f: char 'F'
Table content:

zipWith(%)                            -- apply '%' pairwise to
    mapM id$"01"<$[1..n]              -- all combinations of '0' and '1' of length n
    r                                 -- and the string 'r'
```

Edit: using `\tabular` instead of `\begin{tabular}` (stolen from [@xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146906/34531)).

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>192</s> <s>168</s> 166 bytes

```python
lambda n,l:r'\begin{tabular}{*%dc|c}%s\end{tabular}'%(n,r'\\'.join(map('&'.join,[map(chr,range(97,97+n))+[r'F\\\hline']]+[bin(2**n+i)[3:]+l[n]for i in range(2**n)])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYuxDoMgGIRfhcUCQhqrg9Gka18CGEBRafDXUDs01menGpMON3x3982fZZggj91dRq9H02oE3NcBS2N7B@uizdvrsK1p0jbfZkte0kL7r3FCgO9nia/PyQEZ9Uzw5QQuDmqGwIOG3pKq5FXJgFImAn5IKQfvwGKlmDC7mqcpMEdFUSvmBahuCsghB@i0j5kqSmmcg4MFdaTgOMuy2xFM4w8)

Pretty printed version:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>234</s> <s>229</s> <s>218</s> <s>209</s> <s>205</s> 203 bytes

```python
n,l=input()
print'\\begin{tabular}{'+'c'*n+'|c}\n'+' & '.join(chr(i+97)for i in range(n)+[-27]),'\\\\\n\hline'
i=0
for r in l:print' & '.join(bin(i)[2:].rjust(n,'0')+`r`),r'\\';i+=1
print'\\end{tabular}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7dCoJAEIXvfYq9anbbTdQupMInUcGfLCdklGm9CPPZbaWwOQzDwOE7Z3jZtqdoWch0CdIwWqm8gZEsZFnV3JEmW1ZjV/I8gYYa9qThXc8ZuU/sBPiPHknWLUvUp1jdehYokASXdG8kKZ0eojhXxuHcUNZ2SA14mATe6uXV252/iX9e5RZVGp1znx/j00oyEIDSBRfKsGPBBXUSbk0bum49YVmOJg3MqtD8bv4B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 142 bytes

```
n=>x=>"\\tabular*#{n}c|c#{j(map(chr,97..97+n))}&F\\\\\hline"+'\\\\'.join(j(bin(i)[2to].zfill(n)+x[i])for i:0..len(x))+"\\endtabular"j="&".join
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BCoMwFESvUiLo/40E2y7EQlz2EupCrWIk/ZGQgtR6dhvbzsCbWc1M1jhDWy83kvksc1aWrm6eurbHYKG1fbfBMsKjnqAdbJylQmQpJ8Q1vJW7Bq2oYzzaeyRGowhGaDwVFmdnKvHqldZAyOdCVdgbe1DXRAjdEcyI3P91dP9fslGykH1XtskqctDDBaFI4pP3jz4rxO0D)

Output is in golfed LaTeX form; thanks to xnor for that trick!

<s>This should be able to be golfed to shorter than xnor's Python answer because Proton should in theory never lose to Python lol (in practice I'm bad xD). I may steal some tricks from xnor ;P</s>

Managed to now be shorter by making some things into variables, which I just noticed xnor also did :P

And there we go, -6 bytes by using some Proton golfing tricks.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>196 187</s> 171 bytes

```r
function(m,n){cat("\\tabular{*",n,"c|c}")
write(c(letters[1:n],"F\\\\\\hline",rbind(t(rev(expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),n)))),paste0(m,"\\\\")),"\\endtabular"),1,n+1,sep="&")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xDsIwDER3PsMDcsBCjdgqdeUnKEOauhCpmCh1Aan020tAcMPp7oZ7aemqpRvFa7gJXknM5J0i1LW6ZuxdmjZAQuBffgazeqSgjB57VuU0HG0pJ4JD/dWlD8JAqQnSomLiO/IzOml35xTa3CP2YVAsSmsyKIuiG5SLzIXPAeQlB5b2BwdDlmRraeBYwRrMvHSZXlCRd/t3Q3uzvAE)

Output similar to [the Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146900/80010). `expand.grid` from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164409/80010).

For the record, using `xtable` from the eponym package is not <s>much</s> shorter since one has to specify a lot of options to match the spec, in addition to including the package:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 187 bytes

```r
function(m,n){u=rbind(apply(expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),n)),1,rev),m)
rownames(u)=c(letters[1:n],"F")
print(xtable(t(u),dig=0,align=c(rep("c",n+1),"|c}")),hl=0,include.r=F)}
library(xtable)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc49DsIwDIbhvcfIZAsLtWJDysolEEOapMVSaiI35UfA2UuQYPH0@tGn62DXYRFf@CIwkeBzsdqzBHA5pwfEe3YStqNyAI0ZEs8F2n2HNUXqSOMVacJGLzdxU5xhQeshxVKizsduLycyB4NNVpYC9@L6FKHUigKPtiWXeJT68bWNNySbSpuXf5vKn1MtWHxaQtyqPeC7Sdyr08dPwnUADy21dUn3v0g7XD8)