# Sample space of n consecutive coin flips

Tags: code-golf, math

Taking a positive integer `n` as input, print the sample space of `n` consecutive coin flips. The coin is fair, with two sides `H` and `T`, each with probability `0.5`.

For example,

Input - `3`

Output -

```
HHH
HHT
HTH
HTT
THH
THT
TTH
TTT
```

**Rules**

- [Standard loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- You may print the elements out of order, but all of them should be present.
- You may use any form of output, as long as heads and tails are displayed as 'H' and 'T', and all elements are distuinguishable.

This is `code-golf`, so the shortest code in bytes wins. Good luck!

Comment: Is a list of lists/strings acceptable? Could we use `1`s and `0`s (or booleans or even `1`s and `2`s or similar)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan yes, I'll add that to the question. Any way of output is acceptable as long as you can distinguish between elements.  But only H for heads and T for tails is allowed.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/102835/80214 does this answer your question?

Comment: @Razetime yes. Should have searched for cartesian product questions before submitting. Sorry!

Comment: I'd say that since order doesn't matter here, it must be H/T, and doesn't need to support longer lists, this challenge has enough merit standing on its own, but it's possible that every answer will just use the Cartesian Power builtin.

Comment: Welcome to CGCC, by the way!

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms thanks! I have known about code-golf SE for a while, and I've been reading a lot of answers on interesting questions. Finally made an account, and I'll try my best to contribute!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁾HTṗ
```

A monadic Link accepting a non-negative integer which yields a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R4z6PkIc7p/8/3B75/78xAA)** (footer calls the Link and joins with newline characters)

#### How?

```
⁾HTṗ - Link: integer, n
⁾HT  - list o characters = ['H', 'T']
   ṗ - (that) Cartesian power (n)
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast, nice answer!

Comment: It's pretty easy when there are relevant built-ins in a language one knows well.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
lambda x:product(*["HT"]*x);from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqqAoP6U0uURDK1rJI0QpVqtC0zqtKD9XIbMktagkPz@nWCEztyC/qETrf0FRZl6JRk5mcYlGmoaxpqYmFxeKkClQ6D8A)

I like my recursive approach better, but unfortunately, using module built-ins is shorter lol.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 54 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x and[y+q for y in f(x-1)for q in"HT"]or" "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRocKqQiExLyW6UrtQIS2/SKFSITNPIU2jQtdQE8QtBHKVPEKUYvOLlBSU/hcUZeaVaKRpGGtqcnHBOKaamv8B)

-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <sup>41 40</sup> 39 bytes

```bash
eval echo $(printf \{H,T}%.0s `seq $1`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifpqFZ/T@1LDFHITU5I19BRaOgKDOvJE0hptpDJ6RWVc@gWCGhOLVQQcUwQfN/LVeaghEQG/8HAA)

*-1 thanks to pxeger*

*-1 thanks to Digital Trauma*

### Alternative, also 41 bytes

```bash
(($1))&&f $[$1-1] $2'{H,T}'||eval echo $2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifpqFZ/V9DQ8VQU1NNLU1BJVrFUNcwVkHFSL3aQyekVr2mJrUsMUchNTkjHyj4v5YrTcEQiI2A2Pg/AA)

Comment: One of the sets of `$()` can be backticks `\`\``

Comment: [A different approach for 39](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifpqFZ/b84tVBBN03VQMUwXcEwVcWwpjg1RUE/2kDXPFY/Jca6Ut/CUt8jRP9/LVeagiEQGwGxMRCbALHp///GAA)

Comment: Or escape the `{` instead of single quotes, [also 39](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifpqFZ/T@1LDFHITU5I19BRaOgKDOvJE0hptpDJ6RWVc@gWCGhOLVQQcUwQfN/LVeaghEQG/8HAA)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 52 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,a=[''])=>x?f(--x,a.flatMap(n=>[n+'H',n+'T'])):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVajQifRNlpdPVbT1q7CPk1DVxcooJeWk1jim1igkWdrF52nre6hrgMkQ4CKNK0S/yfn5xXn56Tq5eSna6RpGGpqcqGKGGGIGGOImGCImGpq/gcA)

A pretty simple recursive approach.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 62 bytes

```
=IF(MOD((INT(SEQUENCE(2^A1)/2^(SEQUENCE(1,A1)-1))),2),"T","H")
```

Answer is spilled into a 2^n by n array of cells.  Starts to get slow around 19.

### Alternative, 65 bytes

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(DEC2BIN(SEQUENCE(2^A1)-1,A1),1,"T"),0,"H")
```

Slightly longer and only works for n<=10.

[Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnAOXUS4i4AoXHVPS?e=0B7Ei7)